# How to use transform with scale in Java 2D graphics

Tags: java, graphics, transform

I am using `scale(double x, double y);` for scaling my drawing canvas.
Next I am using `g2.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), x, y));` for rotate `ImageIcon`.

When I use both (`scale` and `Transform`) transform not working correctly.

How to use it?

example:

```
scale
drawCircle (ok coordinates)
saveDefaultTranfsorm
setTransform
drawImage (wrong coordinates !!!!!!)
setDefautTransfor (ok coordinates)
drawOtherStuff (ok coordinates)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: plz provide a code example

Comment: Your example code looks weird.

Comment: Remember, when you scale the graphics, the coordinates change. You over need to transform then scale (or the other way)